# SDE existence and uniqueness

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I am working on the following problem in a course using "Stochastic Differential Equations" by Oksendal.

Consider the two coupled It SDEs.

$dXt=−λX_tdt+σdB_t$

$dYt=−\sin Y_tdt+sX_t\cos Ytdt$

Where $λ,σ,s$ are constant parameters. $B_t$ is standard brownian motion.

Now I am asked to show whether existence and uniquenes of a strong solution can be guaranteed from Lipschitz continuity of and linear bounds on the functions. My question is twofold. How do I write the above as a system and how to show the bounds and the Lipschitz condition. Does one write it like this?

$
\begin{pmatrix}
dX_t\\dY_t
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda X_t & 0\\
-\sin Y_t & s X_t\cos Y_t
\end{pmatrix}dt
+
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma \\ 0 
\end{pmatrix}
dB_t
$

And then check the conditions elementwise, for each term in the matrix?

Thanks for looking!